# Single SSL certificate for Multiple load balancer

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, load-balancing

Can I have a single SSL certificate for two load balancer under which same instances are running? each instance has two web sites(but only one application), based on URL hitting on address bar, the web pages are coming.

for this Can I have single SSL certificate for both load balancer or separate certificates?

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

Basically Yes.

It is possible to use same certificate/private key on N places. 
It is also possible to issue N certificates to same DNS name.

I don't quite understand where these certificates will be used. Will it be used by load balancers as ssl server certificate? Or will it be used by the application behind the load balancers?

Either way, it depends on whether the component supports import of pkcs#12/pfx or private key+certificate or not. And it depends on whether you have or can create backup of private key+certificate.

Comment: Yes, that certificate is used by load balancers as SSL certificate

Comment: Then the third paragraph is a valid answer to your question.